# Validate HTML dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I want to display the text with HTML tags.

I am having the following code:

```
<pre th:id="'answer' + ${answerStat.index}"></pre>
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

$("#answer" + [[${answerStat.index}]]).html([[${answer.value}]]);

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

It works perfect, but `answer.value` was inputed by user earlier and it may contain syntax errors (like unclosed tag). And if `answer.value` contains the syntax error, it leads to error.

So, how can I dynamically check is `answer.value` has no syntax errors?
Thank you, hope you will help me.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you need. Are users going to be inputting raw HTML? What about scripts? Is sanitization important? What are the valid characters to be accepted? HTML can be written in a ton of ways and you will not be able to evaluate 'valid html' without some complicated regex statements.

Comment: Why are you letting the user input HTML?

Comment: Because I make a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `try/catch` statement.

The syntax is:

```
try{
    //code to be tried here
}
catch(e){
    //error handling here
    //e is the error thrown by the try
}
```

So if your `answer.value` has an error, and it is inside a `try/catch` statement, the `catch` statement will run. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) for details.